# How to make a new profile?

Tags: 14.04

My mum dad and brother all use my computer, so I thought of making accounts but I am not sure how to make an account.

I want to make an account that has few privileges like a normal account, not administrator.

I am using trusty tahr 14.04

Thanks!

Comment: [Add a new user account - Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-add.html)

Answer (score 0):

Load up a terminal or console window and use the following command:

```
sudo useradd <username>
```

That will create a basic user inside of ubuntu for you.  When a user needs to use administrator rights it will prompt them.